# How to configure kafka connect sink to write in multiple table in the same time?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

The use case is to use a kafka connector to write in multiple tables in the same time.

Edit after the first comment

```
"insert.mode": "upsert",
"delete.enabled": "true",
"topics": "cars.best, airplanes.best",
"table.name.format": "CARS, AIRPLANES",
"pk.mode": "record_key",
"pk.fields": "cars_id" - for one of the tables ,                                                                       "pk.fields": "airplane_id" - for the other one of the tables ,
```

What can it be the setting from getting the carst topic to CARS table and airplae topic to AIRPLANES

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC Sink connector (along with most other sink connectors) write to tables/collections based on the names of the topics being consumed, but only under one server/schema/database.

So, set `topics` or `topicPattern` to consume from multiple topics

Comment: I updated a bit the question cos i am not sure how the config can look like and documentation did not help

Comment: If you want to remove `.best` suffix, then you should look at [RegexRouter](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html). `table.name.format` cannot have commas, last I checked. And it is not needed if you just drop the suffix from both topics. Also, `pk.fields` needs to exist in every topic/table that you are reading; therefore, I doubt airplanes topic has `cars_id`, so your shown config will not work. You should run two separate connectors.

Comment: so basically there is no solution to have it in the same connector :(

Comment: You can use the same connector **class**, but you need to deploy more than one config for it,  given that you have different `pk.fields` for each topic